# AngularJS error when using splice()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typeerror

I am trying to delete a record both from scope and DB in angularjs but I am getting error. Although my record is deleting but not deleting in scope and shows error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Here is my code.

```
<a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</a>
```

```
$scope.deleteUser = function (uid) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this?")) {
        $http.post("functions.php?type=deleteUser&uid=" + uid).success(function (data) {
            $scope.users.splice(uid, 1);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: The first argument to splice should be the index of the item you want to remove, not the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to get `user` before `post`, then

```
var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
$scope.users.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. :) and I just use angularjs property $index in html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do following thing:
1.   As you are binding data to first time in init method.

```
var bindToGrid=function(){
  $scope.usersData=data;//from api
 }
```

2.   On delete you are calling api that is right.

```
 $scope.deleteUser = function (uid) {
  if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this?")){
  $http.post("functions.php?type=deleteUser&uid="+uid).success(function(data){
    $scope.users.splice(uid, 1);
  });
 }
 };
```

3.   But on the success you have to call init again as follows

```
 $scope.deleteUser = function (uid) {
  if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this?")){
  $http.post("functions.php?type=deleteUser&uid="+uid).success(function(data){
    $scope.bindToGrid();
  });
 }
 };
```

That will rebind to your model object and will reflect changes.